# Why vbscript is not retrieving data from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, vbscript

I have this vbscript that I'm using to update registry based on the information on the database. There are two parts to this: One that retrieves user's information from Active Directory, and the other retrieves some other information from MySQL database. The part where it connects and retrieves the AD info is working fine, but the part where it connects to MySQL is not. Here's the code.

```vb
Const strCompanyName = "Company"

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Create the ADsystem Information Object
Set objADSystemInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
'Get the current information into a new object
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objADSystemInfo.UserName)

On Error Resume Next

'Office Details
oShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Common\UserInfo\UserInitials", objUser.sAMAccountName, "REG_SZ"
oShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Common\UserInfo\UserName", objUser.givenName & " " & objUser.sn, "REG_SZ"
' If set by installer Company Name is overidden on load.
oShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Common\UserInfo\Company", strCompanyName, "REG_SZ"


'Connect to MySQL Database
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adUseClient = 3

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'DSN already exists in ODBC
objConnection.Open "DSN=members;"
objRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient
objRecordset.ActiveConnection = objConnection
x=msgbox("Connecting to db",0, "HI")
objRecordset.Open "SELECT ID, USER_TITLE FROM staff WHERE USER_ID = '" & objUser.sAMAccountName & "'", objConnection

'For Acrobat 11
regPath = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\11.0\" 'For Acrobat Pro 11
x=msgbox("Setting registry", 0, "")
'Set Acrobat Identity Info
oShell.RegWrite regPath & "Identity\tEmail", objUser.mail, "REG_SZ"
oShell.RegWrite regPath & "Identity\tName", objUser.givenName & " " & objUser.sn, "REG_SZ"
oShell.RegWrite regPath & "Identity\tFirstName", objRecordset(0) , "REG_SZ"    'For ID #
oShell.RegWrite regPath & "Identity\tLastName", objUser.sn, "REG_SZ"
oShell.RegWrite regPath & "Identity\tCorporation", strCompany, "REG_SZ"
oShell.RegWrite regPath & "Identity\tDepartment", "Department", "REG_SZ"
oShell.RegWrite regPath & "Identity\tTitle", objRecordset(1) , "REG_SZ"   'For User's title

objRecordset.Close
objConnection.Close

WScript.quit
```

This setup worked when I initially created, but has stopped updating the registry with the data retrieved from MySQL since. The portion where it's writing to registry still works; I tried it with some constant which updated the registry upon running the code. I think the problem lies somewhere in connecting to MySQL database. I looked at pretty much everything I possibly could think of. I even added a messagebox (not shown) after the query to see whether it retrieved the data or not, but it didn't even make the `msgbox` pop up. Any idea why?

Comment: Disable/Remove the EVIL global and nowhere-checked `On Error Resume Next`, test again, and look at the error message(s) **before** you ask a VBScript question here.

Comment: Ok. I'll check that. Thanks

Comment: You're right. I didn't even realized that. This is the only vbscript I have ever written. Well, turned out the problem was with mismatched architecture for ODBC connector. It's working now. Just wasted hours trying to fix a simple fix just cause of "EVIL" global On Error Resume Next. Thanks for your help, mate.